# Unable to connect to websocket using swift in xcode project getting error: Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, websocket, socket.io

I'm working on iOS project, I need to connect to the websocket, below is code to connect websockt,

```
class WebSocketTaskConnection: NSObject, WebSocketConnection, URLSessionWebSocketDelegate {
    var delegate: WebSocketConnectionDelegate?
    var webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask!
    var urlSession: URLSession!
    let delegateQueue = OperationQueue()
    
    init(token: String) {
        super.init()
        
        let tokenFilter = token.substring(from: 7)
        
        
        var components = URLComponents(string: WebSocketUrls.baseSocketUrl)!
        components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: tokenFilter),
                                 URLQueryItem(name: "os_type", value: "ios")]
        
        print("WebSocketTaskConnection URL", components.url ?? "---")
        
        urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: delegateQueue)
        webSocketTask = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: components.url!)
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didOpenWithProtocol protocol: String?) {
        self.delegate?.onConnected(connection: self)
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didCloseWith closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?) {
        self.delegate?.onDisconnected(connection: self, error: nil)
    }
    
    func connect() {
        webSocketTask.resume()
        
        listen()
    }
    
    func disconnect() {
        webSocketTask.cancel(with: .goingAway, reason: nil)
    }
    
    func listen()  {
        webSocketTask.receive { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                self.delegate?.onError(connection: self, error: error)
            case .success(let message):
                switch message {
                case .string(let text):
                    self.delegate?.onMessage(connection: self, text: text)
                case .data(let data):
                    self.delegate?.onMessage(connection: self, data: data)
                @unknown default:
                    fatalError()
                }
                
                self.listen()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func send(text: String) {
        webSocketTask.send(URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string(text)) { error in
            if let error = error {
                self.delegate?.onError(connection: self, error: error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func send(data: Data) {
        webSocketTask.send(URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.data(data)) { error in
            if let error = error {
                self.delegate?.onError(connection: self, error: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to connect to websocket, I get following error

```
SOCKET >> Connection error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://chat.wifiattendance.com:3015/?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIxMDk1NSIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoiZmFyZXlhLmtAY2xvdWR4cGVydGUuY29tIiwiRW1wbG95ZWVJZCI6IjUwNTMiLCJPcmdJZCI6IjEiLCJMb2NhdGlvbklkIjoiODg3IiwiTG9jYXRpb25OYW1lIjoiQXVyYW5nYWJhZCIsIlJvbGVJZCI6IjIxNCIsIlJvbGVOYW1lIjoiRW1wbG95ZWUiLCJuYmYiOjE3MDU1NjA1MjksImV4cCI6MTcwNTgxOTcyOSwiaWF0IjoxNzA1NTYwNTI5fQ.PC-ha0pOQkzKVL-ePCVEfocSMT-TyFxZ_npGOJVfRyQ&os_type=ios, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://chat.wifiattendance.com:3015/?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIxMDk1NSIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoiZmFyZXlhLmtAY2xvdWR4cGVydGUuY29tIiwiRW1wbG95ZWVJZCI6IjUwNTMiLCJPcmdJZCI6IjEiLCJMb2NhdGlvbklkIjoiODg3IiwiTG9jYXRpb25OYW1lIjoiQXVyYW5nYWJhZCIsIlJvbGVJZCI6IjIxNCIsIlJvbGVOYW1lIjoiRW1wbG95ZWUiLCJuYmYiOjE3MDU1NjA1MjksImV4cCI6MTcwNTgxOTcyOSwiaWF0IjoxNzA1NTYwNTI5fQ.PC-ha0pOQkzKVL-ePCVEfocSMT-TyFxZ_npGOJVfRyQ&os_type=ios}
```

I have tried everything i found on internet like resetting simulator and xcode also getting same error when I run code on my iPhone.

If anyone has some idea how to fix this, please help.

Thanks!

Restart and reset simulator, reinstalled app on simulator and iPhone

Comment: Having the exact same error trying to estabish a connection to a simple websocket. 
1. Added dummy /get http call to server to validate isAlive.
2.Ensures Socket.io was up to date (Implementation was correct)
3. Run both simulator and server on same machine to use localhost
4. No logging or errors on the server.
5. Connection Stable

The farthest I have gotten is, tracing w/ wireshark that immediately after each GET request from the client, there's a <FIN, ACK> packet from the client, indicating that the client is closing the connection. Is iOS killing the connection request on purpose?